# Android: detecting removed item in ObservableList

Tags: java, android, android-databinding, observablelist

I am using ObservableList in my model for binding. When the item is removed from ObservableList, I want to know about what item has been removed. So I am using `ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback`.

When the item is removed, it will called `onItemRangeRemoved()`. But the problem is the item has been removed from the ObservableList in `onItemRangeRemoved()`.

```
catDatas.addOnListChangedCallback(new ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList<CatData>>()
{
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ObservableList<CatData> sender)
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemRangeChanged(ObservableList<CatData> sender, int positionStart, int itemCount)
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemRangeInserted(ObservableList<CatData> sender, int positionStart, int itemCount)
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemRangeMoved(ObservableList<XROrderItemData> sender, int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount)
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemRangeRemoved(ObservableList<CatData> sender, int positionStart, int itemCount)
    {
        for (int idx = itemCount - 1; idx >= 0; idx--)
        {
            CatData data = sender.get(idx + positionStart);  //this line will throw index out of bounds exception
            ...
            ...
            ...
            uninitData(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea how to capture the items that are removed?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The folks at Google overlooked the removeAll() method, so it does not notify observers. To fix this, use this custom class:

```
class MyObservableArrayList<T>: ObservableArrayList<T>() {

    override fun removeAll(elements: Collection<T>): Boolean {
        var success = false
        elements.forEach { if (super.remove(it)) success = true }
        return success
    }

}
```

Comment: If you encounter this bug, please star the issue I created on the Google Issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113075721

Comment: Hi Peter, this doesn't fix the behavior of Remove() nor RemoveAll() where the item has been removed from *ObservableList* when the `onItemRangeRemoved()` is raised. But +1 for suggesting to override ObservableArrayList.

Comment: Ah, sorry I should have read your question more carefully. In your case, overriding the class and onItemRangeRemoved() is the way to go. Of course it's been a year and you've probably moved on, haha.